# How to user long value as a `Date` type in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 7.10.1. My document has a field `timestamp` whose value is long, e.g. `1624841520000`. I tried to change it to use `Date` type but failed:

```
PUT myindex/_mapping
{
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date" 
        }
      }
    
}
```

The error response is:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "mapper [timestamp] cannot be changed from type [long] to [date]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "mapper [timestamp] cannot be changed from type [long] to [date]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

How can I use this field as `date`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the mapping type, you will need to delete the index and create the mapping before indexing the document.

Later versions, starting with 7.11 using the Elastic license, have the option to create [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/runtime-mapping-fields.html#runtime-mapping-fields), that allows to change the mapping at query time, but this is not possible with version 7.10.

Comment: Does this mean I can use `date` type for `long` value when I create the new index?

Comment: No, in version 7.10 if you have a field mapped as long you can't use it as a date, you need to delete the index, map the field as date and then reindex. From version 7.11 you have the option to use a different mapping at query time only, it won't change the original mapping, but allows you to query a field with a epoch time as a date even if it is mapped as long for example. Also if you want to use the field as a date in Kibana for example, when creating the index pattern, you need to map it as a date field.

Answer (score 0):

Create or update like this should solve your problem:

```
PUT myindex/_doc/<the_doc_id_of_your_data>
{
   "data_field": "data_value",
   "timestamp": 1626336886075
}
```

Where <the_doc_id_of_your_data> should be replaced by the doc_id you would specify.

Note that there is a `_doc` lie between your index name and the doc_id.

[Date field type doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/date.html#date) says `date` type accepts milliseconds-since-the-epoch value as input.
The reason you still got that error might be that, according to the [doc of index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index-api-path-params), you must use one of the following form of path parameter:

- `PUT /<target>/_doc/<_id>`
- `PUT /<target>/_create/<_id>`
- `POST /<target>/_create/<_id>`

And you might just missed the path parameter.